# Bit operation such as test() and flip() is not giving the output as expected

Tags: c++, bit

Can anyone please help me with finding out how these are working? I am struggling a lot with that.

Output:

```
All the bits: 00000101
Bit 1 has value : 0
Bit 2 has value : 1
Bit 3 has value : 0
Bit 4 has value : 0
Bit flips 1 = 00000111
Bit flips 2 = 00000011
Bit flips 3 = 00001011
Bit flips 4 = 00011011
```

How they are giving these values? All I know is we have to bitmask and then do or operation for the test ( to check whether it is on or off ) and do XOR operation after bit masking for the flip.
but doing those my answer is not the same as the output.

For example, if we do `test(1)`, then the answer I expect is 0101 (using 0001 as the bitmask and doing an OR operation with 0101 and 0001), but the output I am getting is just 0, which makes no sense to me.

bits= 0000 0101, 0000 0001 ( bitmask)

0000 0101 ( after doing OR operation with bits and bitmask)

Also, if I do `flip(1)`, for example, I expect to get 0000 0001 after doing bitmasking and XOR operation. However my output is giving me a result of 00000111

```
0000 0101
0000 0001 ( bitmask)
---------
0000 0001 ( after Xor operation)
```

```
#include < iostream>
#include < bitset>
int main()
{
std::bitset<8> bits{ 0b0000'0101 };

std::cout << "All the bits: " << bits << '\n';
std::cout << "Bit 1 has value: " << bits.test(1) << '\n';
std::cout << "Bit 2 has value: " << bits.test(2) << '\n';
std::cout << "Bit 3 has value" << bits.test(3) << '\n';
std::cout << "Bit 4 has value" << bits.test(4) << '\n';

std::cout << "Bit flips 1 = " << bits.flip(1) << '\n';
std::cout << "Bit flips 2 = " << bits.flip(2) << '\n';
std::cout << "Bit flips 3 = " << bits.flip(3) << '\n';
std::cout << "Bit flips 4 = " << bits.flip(4) << '\n';
return 0;
}
```

Comment: What output would you expect to get instead? What do you mean by "my answer"? Do you have code that you've written that gives different output than the code you've included? If so, please show that code because people can't debug what they can't see.

Comment: You don't need to think about masking and XOR – `flip(n)` flips the n:th bit from 0 to 1 or from 1 to 0. (You are aware that `flip` doesn't just return the new value, but also modifies the object? And that bit 1 is the second bit, not the first?)

Comment: You know the bits are numbered starting at 0, not 1, right?.... Maybe not. :) It's kind of a standard convention for numbering the bits. Also, the code you show doesn't quite match your output, so it's not the code you compiled and ran. It has syntax errors (`#include < iostream>` shouldn't have the space after `<`). Not sure what's up with that.

Comment: just for an example if we do the test(1), then the answer I am getting is 0101. ( using 0001 AS THE bitmask and doing OR operation with 0101 and 0001)  but the output Im getting is just 0. Which makes no sense to me.

Comment: also if I do flip(1) for an example. I am getting 0000 0001 . after doing bitmasking and XOR operation. But my output is giving me a result of 00000111.

Answer (score 0):

Bits are numbered starting at 0, not 1. That's the convention for bit numbering:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <bitset>

int main()
{
    std::bitset<8> bits{ 0b0000'0101 };

    std::cout << "All the bits: " << bits << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Bit 0 has value: " << bits.test(0) << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Bit 1 has value: " << bits.test(1) << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Bit 2 has value: " << bits.test(2) << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Bit 3 has value: " << bits.test(3) << std::endl;

    std::cout << "Bit flips 0 = " << bits.flip(0) << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Bit flips 1 = " << bits.flip(1) << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Bit flips 2 = " << bits.flip(2) << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Bit flips 3 = " << bits.flip(3) << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```